# How do I find the probability mass function of an individual observation for a multinomial logit model?

Tags: statistics

I know what the probability mass function of a multinomial logit model is. However, I do not know what the probability mass function of an individual observation i, f(yi|xi), is for a multinomial logit model. I would really appreciate if someone could explain how to get the answer and knows the correct answer.[The image on this link is the PMF of a multinomial logit model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wm5tY.png)